# are there generic include files for STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I am interested in having some generic include file that will:

1. include all the necessary files for unordered_map and unordered_set according to the platform you are running it.
2. Do "using namespace" for the right namespace according to the platform I am using.

There is such a mess with these include files, I don't know if I should use tr1/unordered_set, unordered_set, ext/... etc.

I also don't know what namespace I should be using, gnu_cxx, std::tr1, std. Is there some include file with some #ifdef's that does it right?

Also, if I want to define a hash for some type T, how do I define it so that it again works cross-platform? Right now I am using

```
 namespace std {
 namespace tr1 {
 // define hash<T>
 }
 }
```

but that doesn't sound quite right thing to do.

(C++ and STL include files is a mess!)

EDIT:

I am happy to use C++ standard library instead of STL (I didn't know there was a difference, which is another source for confusion.)

Right now, for example, I am using #include  with clang++:

Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix

and it won't find the include file if I do #include[unordered_set].

I added the flag -std=c++0x (-std=c++11 doesn't work).

If I use #include [tr1/unordered_map] then it finds the include file, but I want something that just will cover all bases, and choose the include file from the right place, and not make me change everything from std::... to std::tr1::...

Also, going back to my question, right now I am using

```
typedef unordered_set<T> generic_set;
```

in some template class, and that looks for hash in std::tr1. Is the only way to overcome it is to give the full specification of all hash key functions, etc., in a different name space? I like the simplicity of

```
      unordered_set<T>
```

without having to specify all the hash functions and so on.

Comment: 1) `using namespace x;` is a bad idea. 2) Boost.TR1 is the closest thing you'll get to what you want, I think.

Comment: IIRC declaring anything in the `std::` namespace is undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh hey, I was right: "The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified." from (§17.6.4.2.1/1)

Comment: STL is pretty much ancient history, superseded by the C++ standard library. Is this a question about getting weird ancient include files to play nicely, or about how to do things in the modern world? Because if you stick to the standards, it should just work.

Comment: I am happy to use C++ standard library, but even this doesn't seem to work with clang++ on OSx 10.7.5. See my edit.

Comment: @Jefffrey i believe you are allowed to add to the std namespace for default_delete specialisations

Comment: -std=c++11, not -std=c++11x.

Comment: @aschepler, sorry, yes I tried c++11, it doesn't recognize the flag.

Comment: Update your Xcode. The clang that ships with Xcode is based on LLVM 3.3

Comment: I can't update my Xcode, I tried to. It claims my OSx is too old. I have 10.7.